# USB 3.0 over GigE Ethernet

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet, cable, usb-3

I'm looking for a way to take a USB 3.0 device and access it over GigE Ethernet.  It's a bit of a hard thing to search for because all that comes up are USB network adapters.  The conversion must be USB 3.0 to GigE because it is a high bandwidth application.

I have seen solutions around USB extensions (adapts to one medium, ex, fiber, then back to USB), but I'd prefer to go to GigE and remain there.  The implication of this would be that the USB interface would have to be emulated at the PC.  Possibly, if the remote device were smart enough, it could use Linux's VHCI driver and no 3rd party drivers would be necessary.

Shopping advice aside, is this even possible/does it exist?  Thanks.

Reason behind the request is a combination of factors, but generally I need it for:

1. Further distance
2. Better noise immunity
3. Electrical isolation
4. Better cabling architecture

Comment: Are both your client and server Linux-based?

Comment: No, the remote device is an actual USB peripheral (usb camera).  The client/only PC involved is Linux.

Comment: But you said in your post that you were planning on buying some kind of a remote [bridge device](https://www.blackbox.com/en-us/store/Detail.aspx/LES400-Series-Industrial-Serial-Device-Server---1-Port/LES421A) as well. Is that out of the question now?

Comment: Bridge device is the preferred solution, but I cannot find one and am not sure it even exists.

Comment: ... how much of the USB 3.0 bandwidth are you hoping to make use of? `usbip` is the best option, an will run on a little board - but you won't be able to make use of all of the bandwidth by a long stretch.

Comment: A significant portion. I was hoping to fully utilize GigE bandwidth, but I realize that's only a fraction of USB3's 5 gbps

Answer (score 5):

The built-in Linux *usbip* driver (vhci) supports USB3 SuperSpeed as of kernel 4.13. It doesn't require any special hardware except two Linux systems – you only need to load the apropriate kernel modules, then run `usbip bind` on the server/bridge and `usbip attach` on the client.

(Note that the usbip protocol has no security features whatsoever – no encryption, no authentication, no integrity checking. You'll probably want to use it along with IPsec or another VPN type.)

Comment: Thanks, this is a very close answer and probably my best option.  What I was a solution that doesn't require a 2nd PC, however, that may not exist.  I would think, however, that a device would be on the market that utilizes VHCI to do this without a dedicated PC on the other end.

Comment: @DrTarr: You need *some* sort of device. Any Raspi-Style SoC with a GigE adapter will do, you don't need a "dedicated PC".

Comment: What's the difference between a "dedicated PC" that runs Linux, and a "dedicated device on the market" that runs Linux? Just the general shape?

Comment: I think quite a bit.  An OTS product would be more robust in terms of electrical, software, and hardware, as well as optimized for the task.  Also, less time to get in operation.

Comment: I should say this isn't for a single instance, this is for use in an industrial environment in hundreds of instances.  Maybe that puts it a little more in perspective.